# Laravel migration fails multiple primary keys

Tags: laravel, migration, primary-key

I am trying to create a Migration in Laravel but it fails saying I got multiple primary keys.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('spins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('rid', true, true);
        $table->bigInteger('pid');
        $table->integer('result');
        $table->integer('bet');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary(array('rid', 'pid'));
    });
}
```

The error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multipleprimary key defined 
(SQL: alter table `spins` add primary key `spins_rid_pid_primary` (`rid`, `pid`))
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The autoincrement of `rid` is the problem (second parameter in the line below).

```php
$table->integer('rid', true, true);
```

If you are using InnoDB as MySQL engine it doesn't allow composite primary keys with an auto increment.

**But** if you change to the MyISAM engine it would be possible to do so.

1. Add `$table->engine = 'MyISAM';` to your Migration.
2. Declare the `rid` field as a normal integer column
3. Laravel doesn't provide a method to change existing columns so you need to run a raw SQL query: `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE spins MODIFY rid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');`

---

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('spins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'MyISAM';
        $table->integer('rid')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('pid');
        $table->integer('result');
        $table->integer('bet');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary(array('rid', 'pid'));

        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE spins MODIFY rid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
    });
}
```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ regarding "`Laravel doesn't provide a method to change existing columns`", as above creates the table, the column does **not** exist. Why not keep "`$table->integer('rid', true, true);`" logic? Isn't change to `MyISAM` enough?

Comment: @Top-Master I'm not sure (this was posted 5 years ago for an older Laravel version) but I think the issue here was that if you have a composite primary key `('rid', 'pid')` you cannot have one of it auto incremented because `Blueprint` didn't support it. Not sure if it does support it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary key makes no sense.

You are adding a composite primary key to an auto incrementing column and another column.  The auto incrementing column will already always be unique so you should just have only that be your primary key.

If you need `pid` to be unique, set `rid` to your primary key and add a unique key on `pid`.

```
Schema::create('spins', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('rid');
    $table->bigInteger('pid');
    $table->integer('result');
    $table->integer('bet');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unique('pid');
});
```

If for some reason you do need your primary key to include `rid` and `pid`, this seems to work for me.

```
CREATE TABLE `spins` (
  `rid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `result` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `bet` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rid`, `pid`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple primary keys on a single table. You can have a composite primary key, which is a primary key made from two or more columns. Apparently [Blueprint does not support creating composite keys](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355), so you'll have to use the query builder if you want to use composite keys.

Otherwise you can just choose `pid` or `rid` as your primary key.

Comment: `Blueprint` does support composite primary keys, you just can't have one of those keys be auto incrementing.  I usually do composite primary keys on pivot tables using `Blueprint` and it works fine.

Comment: @user3158900 Hmm that is to bad it can't auto increment :/ ill have to try another way then

Comment: If you really need this primary key, it's probably possible through the query builder and is definitely possible through raw SQL.